# React: mapping over a list and passing the value into the props of another component

Tags: reactjs

This is the chunk of code:

```
export function ViewHeaders(props){
    console.log(props.pitches)
    return (
        props.pitchKeys.map((pitchKey, index) => {
            console.log(pitchKey)
            //prints as expected
            return (
                <div>
                    <h1> {pitchKey} </h1>
                    <ViewPitches pitches={props.pitches} key={pitchKey}/>
                </div>
            )
        })
    )
};


function ViewPitches(props) {
    console.log(props.key)
    // printing as undefined
    return(
        props.pitches.map((pitch, index) => {
            if (pitch.pitchName == props.key) {
                return (<div>{pitch.id}</div>)    
            }
        })
    )
}
```

I am iterating over a list `props.pitchKeys` and inside `ViewHeaders` printing out each `pitchKey` as expected.

I am then passing `pitchKey` in as a prop into `ViewPitches`.

However when I print out `props.key` it's coming back as undefined. Do I have to do something special when passing in the returned value of a .map() into the props?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`key` is a "reserved word" so it's not being passed as a prop to your component, but being used to verify which item has changed. Change the name of the prop and it should work.

As [React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html#keys) says:

> Keys help React identify which items have changed, are added, or are removed. Keys should be given to the elements inside the array to give the elements a stable identity